# Simplified visitor pattern

Tags: java, visitor-pattern

Here is a visitor pattern implemented in Java to evaluate an expression like (1 + 2) + 3. The code here is inspired by the code example at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Sources.

```
interface Node
{
    public int accept(Visitor v);
}

class ConstantNode implements Node
{
    public int constant;

    public ConstantNode(int constant)
    {
        this.constant = constant;
    }

    public int accept(Visitor v) {
        return v.visit(this);
    }
}

class SumNode implements Node
{
    public Node left;
    public Node right;

    public SumNode(Node left, Node right)
    {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public int accept(Visitor v) {
        return v.visit(this);
    }
}

interface Visitor
{
    public int visit(ConstantNode n);
    public int visit(SumNode n);
}

class EvalVisitor implements Visitor
{
    public int visit(ConstantNode n) {
        return n.constant;
    }

    public int visit(SumNode n) {
        return n.left.accept(this) + n.right.accept(this);
    }
}

public class VisitorDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // First make an expression tree to represent the following.
        //
        //        +
        //       / \
        //      +   3
        //     / \
        //    1   2
        Node a = new ConstantNode(1);
        Node b = new ConstantNode(2);
        Node c = new ConstantNode(3);
        Node d = new SumNode(a, b);
        Node e = new SumNode(d, c);

        Visitor visitor = new EvalVisitor();
        int result = e.accept(visitor);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I understand that at each level of recursion, which `visit()` method to invoke depends on the type of the visitor (in this case `evalVisitor`) as well as on the type of the node (`ConstantNode` or `SumNode`), hence the need for double dispatch. But this kind of coding to implement double dispatch using `accept()` and `visit()` methods seem too convoluted to me. But almost all examples of visitor pattern I have seen use this approach of passing the visitor to the node via `accept()` which in turn calls the visitor's `visit()` method to perform double-dispatch.

Why can't the code examples be simpler like this?

```
interface Node
{
}

class ConstantNode implements Node
{
    public int constant;

    public ConstantNode(int constant)
    {
        this.constant = constant;
    }
}

class SumNode implements Node
{
    public Node left;
    public Node right;

    public SumNode(Node left, Node right)
    {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

interface Visitor
{
    public int visit(Node n) throws Exception;
}

class EvalVisitor implements Visitor
{
    public int visit(Node n) throws Exception {
        if (n instanceof ConstantNode) {
            return ((ConstantNode) n).constant;
        } else if (n instanceof SumNode) {
            return this.visit(((SumNode) n).left) + this.visit(((SumNode) n).right);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unsupported node");
        }
    }
}

public class SimpleVisitorDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // First make an expression tree to represent the following.
        //
        //        +
        //       / \
        //      +   3
        //     / \
        //    1   2
        Node a = new ConstantNode(1);
        Node b = new ConstantNode(2);
        Node c = new ConstantNode(3);
        Node d = new SumNode(a, b);
        Node e = new SumNode(d, c);

        Visitor visitor = new EvalVisitor();
        int result = visitor.visit(e);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

In this code sample, I have completely eliminated the need to implement `apply()` in each node and the total logic of visiting including the logic for double dispatch is now contained within the visitor class only.

I have the following question:

Can you objectively enumerate the problems with the simplified visitor pattern in terms of maintanability or efficiency of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't the code examples be simpler, [...]

Because your example replaces a virtual dispatch with a `switch` dispatch (which you implemented as a chain of `if`s on the object subtype). This approach is extremely hard to maintain, because you get no help from the compiler in detecting changes to your inheritance hierarchy.

The specific problem with the simplified implementation is in that last `else`, where you return zero. A more common solution is to throw an exception there, because you really don't know what kind of node you've got.

Now imagine extending the hierarchy with, say, a `SubtractNode`. This would naturally require an addition of a method to `Visitor` interface, making sure that all visitors are forced to handle the new node subtype at compile time.

Simplified example, on the other hand, would continue to compile, and in your case, it would also continue to run, returning a wrong result for `SubtractNode`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have now edited the code to throw an exception in the else part to account for unsupported node types. So now if we introduce a `SubtractNode`, the code would still continue to compile although it would throw an exception at runtime if `SubtractNode` is encountered. But the fact that it would still continue to compile seems like a good point that demonstrates that the simplified version is difficult to maintain as compared to the `apply()-visit()` pattern.

Comment: @LoneLearner That's right - I think the biggest value that comes from the visitor pattern as a double dispatch mechanism is its ability to catch missing type-specific branches at compile time. Unfortunately, this is also its biggest weakness, because it makes it harder to modify the hierarchy of visitable classes.

Comment: I am a little confused about how visitor pattern makes it any more harder to modify the hierarchy of visitable classes than non-visitor pattern (i.e. operations such as `evaluate()`, `print()`, etc. defined in visitable classes) does. In a non-visitor pattern, if the hierarchy between visitables change, then each operation method defined in each affected visitable has to be modified. In a visitor pattern, in each visitor class, the visit() method for each affected visitable needs to be modified. Sounds like equal amount of work in both cases.

Comment: @LoneLearner Every time you add a new node to the visitable side you need to update `Visitor` interface with a new method. This is fine if you own the code, but if you base your code on some library that supplies a visitor it becomes a problem. Suppose that the code from your example is a library, that you cannot modify, and now you want to expand it by adding `SubtractNode`. Since `Visitor` knows nothing about `SubtractNode`, there is no clean way of extending the hierarchy from the outside.